# iOS silent push notification not triggering everytime in backgrounded state

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am triggering a [silent push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) in my background and in `didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` method I'm firing a local notification to check whether silent notifications are fired or not.

The behaviour of silent notifications is unreliable so far as it doesn't fire every time.

I have already enabled the background mode and remote notifications from the capabilities.

I want to fire silent notifications when the app is in the background state or when the app goes in suspended state.

[image: This is my APN's load]

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty sounds string the payload and check for the delivery.
Change your payload something like this..

```
{
    "aps": {
         "content-available": 1,
         "sound": ""
       }
}
```